# Using Java to perform XSLT which calls Java function

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

I am new to XSLT. Previously, I was used to using commandline to perform XSLT. Just like this:

```
@echo off
set XALAN_JAR=%OPENCCG_HOME%\lib\xalan.jar
java -classpath .;%XALAN_JAR% org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process -IN recommend_person.xml -XSL planner.xsl -OUT people_graph.xml
```

This worked well and I was able to call Java functions inside the `planner.xsl` file. But now I want to do the same thing inside a Java program and I wrote program like this:

```
/**
 * Created by Zhao on 2016/8/19.
 */
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class xslTest {
    // 1. Instantiate a TransformerFactory.
    private TransformerFactory tFactory;

    // 2. Use the TransformerFactory to process the stylesheet Source and
    //    generate a Transformer.
    private Transformer transformer;

    private FileOutputStream outStream;
    // setup the input, output and xsl
    private StreamSource xsl;
    private StreamSource input;
    private StreamResult output;

    public void xslTest(String inputFile, String outputFile, String XSLFile) {

        try {
            tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            xsl = new StreamSource(XSLFile);
            input = new StreamSource(inputFile);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            output = new StreamResult(outStream);

            transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsl);

            transformer.transform(input, output);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.printf(
                "Transform from %s to %s using %s performed",
                inputFile, outputFile, XSLFile
        );
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        xslTest test = new xslTest();

        String inputFile = "C:/xslt/recommend_person.xml";
        String outputFile = "C:/xslt/output.xml";
        String XSLFile = "C:/xslt/planner.xsl";

        test.xslTest(inputFile, outputFile, XSLFile);
    }
}
```

My IDE tells me there are many errors like:

```
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #20; Column #55; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #23; Column #65; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
Transform from C:/xslt/recommend_person.xml to C:/xslt/output.xml using C:/xslt/planner.xsl performed
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #23; Column #65; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #26; Column #82; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #26; Column #82; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #29; Column #129; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #29; Column #129; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #33; Column #68; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #33; Column #68; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #36; Column #72; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #36; Column #72; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #39; Column #71; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #39; Column #71; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #51; Column #67; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #51; Column #67; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #57; Column #60; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #57; Column #60; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #60; Column #72; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #60; Column #72; Unknown error in XPath.
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #65; Column #48; Variable idgen is directly or indirectly referencing itself!
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #16; Column #60; javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeIdGen
file:///C:/xslt/planner.xsl; Line #65; Column #48; Unknown error in XPath.
```

`NodeIdGen` is the Java class I used in the XSL file. It works well when I used the commandline to do the transform.

Comment: ClassNotFoundException probably means that something isn't on your classpath. Check your IDE configuration. Try adding a reference to the missing class from your main application, to see if that gets picked up.

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks! It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. Problem solved! This has nothing to do with XSLT. Just a classpath problem: you need to add the class file which is used in the XSL file to your project classpath.